# How to persist a redis ACL in ElastiCache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

Is it possible to persist a redis ACL e.g with the python client - something like this:

```
redis_client.acl_setuser(
    enabled=True,
    username=user_id,
    passwords=["+" + password],
    keys="*",
    commands=["+@all", "-select", f"+select|1"],
)
redis_client.acl_save()
```

with ElastiCache?

---

An alternative to `redis_client.acl_save()` is `redis_client.config_rewrite()` but I am wondering if either will actually persist.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can.
Elasticache Redis restricts lots of ACL and all config related command.
Check this -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html